# Storing long strings (CLOB) in Hsqldb databases?

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

So here's some code:

```
statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE SomeTable(id INTEGER IDENTITY, " +
    "text CLOB)");
```

which throws an exception "Wrong data type: CLOB in statement [...]". Is there a way to store CLOBs in Hsqldb databases? The documentation says it is. Or maybe my knowledge of SQL is so rusty that I forgot how to define them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try LONGVARCHAR instead of CLOB

Comment: Good answer but it does not explain why the 2.2.8 is giving such error and it should be supported.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with version 2.3.2

Answer (score 4):

In version 2.0 and above, CLOB is a supported type. For your example, you should add PRIMARY KEY explicitly.

```
statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE SomeTable(id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, " +
    "text CLOB)");
```